# How to define a function that works with no argument or with 3 arguments?

Tags: typescript

I would like to write a function that works with no argument or with 3 arguments but it wouldn't work if the user pass one o two arguments.​ It is possible?

Answer (score 0):

Well I figured out how to do it:

I used an object as optional argument with 3 required key:

initialFetchPosts(**query?:{field:string,comparison:any,value:string}**){...}